# What is the difference between DDE & WCF & WMI & WFP?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, wmi, dde

As I mentioned in the question, What is the difference between DDE & WCF & WMI & WFP? and when should I use eachone. I searched alot in google but I didn't get the point.

Is there any intersection or common functions between them?

Comment: Maybe you need some sort of IPC?

Comment: Don't use DDE unless you __really__ have to.

Comment: DDE is deprecated and is not supported under .NET (unless you manually implement it if you're into that kind of thing ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDE is an old model used for Inter-Process Communication in Windows.

WCF is a .NET framework for building network applications.

WMI is a extension to the Windows Driver Model which allows getting notifications or information about hardware.

Comment: so what is the new technology of DDE?

Comment: You can use WCF with the NetNamedPipeBinding

Comment: H_wardak: Do you need to communicate on the same machine or on network level? Also what language are you using and what OS

Comment: actually, I'm using C#, Windows OS

Comment: So you want .NET Remoting then (google it for tutorials). .NET Remoting works on the same machine or on network level. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting for more .NET works on Linux and MacOS too via Mono (open source alternative to Microsoft .NET).

Comment: you mean that we can run C# application on Linux or MacOS?

Comment: You can run C# code on Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android, iOS, Windows Phone 7 via Mono http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29

Comment: Please note that .NET Remoting is a legacy technology http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72x4h507%28VS.85%29.aspx, I would follow @RichardBlewett's advice